# BreezeJS executeQueryLocally and return string

Tags: breeze

I can execute a query in breeze from the server (using EF) which returns a load of boostrap data thus:

```
em.executeQuery(_lookupsQuery).then(function (data) {
_lookups = data.results;
console.log(_lookups[0].currentUserId);
```

This returns currentUserId which is a guid. I then store em using local storage for querying locally later:

```
_lookups = [{
currentUserId: em.executeQueryLocally(_lookupsQuery.toType(breeze.DataType.String))
}];
```

However this does not work as it requires an entity type e.g:
     em.executeQueryLocally(_lookupsQuery.toType(em.metadataStore.getEntityType("Measure")))

Since currentUserId is a guid I am not sure which type to cast the query to. I have tried to make an entity type on the client just for this but it does not seem to work. Any help on solving this would be appreciated.

Edit:

After a suggestion, I modified lookups:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<object> Lookups()
    {
        var currentUser = await UserManager.FindById(Guid.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
        var companyId = currentUser.CompanyId.Value;
        return new
        {
            currentUser = new
            {
                Id = currentUser.Id
            }
        };
    }
```

When querying remotely using:

```
em.executeQuery(_lookupsQuery).then(function (data) {
_lookups = data.results;
console.log(_lookups[0].currentUser);
```

I get:

Object { id="f2dceb4b-29e7-4533-99e2-2052dc39143a"}

I set up the new entity type:

```
            metadataStore.addEntityType({
                shortName: "CurrentUser",
                dataProperties: {
                    id: { dataType: "String", isPartOfKey: true }
                }
            });
```

but when I query locally:

```
_lookups = [{
    currentUser: em.executeQueryLocally(_lookupsQuery.toType(em.metadataStore.getEntityType("CurrentUser")))        }];
console.log(_lookups[0].currentUser);
```

this returns []

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try my answer below?  I see you made an edit but it doesn't notify any previous answerers if you don't comment or something on my answer.  You say 'When I query remotely' but your query shows executeQueryLocally, so it is only looking locally of course..

Comment: Hi, yes I was trying your first example and I meant query locally

Comment: I added an example entityQuery in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can handle it.  I am only going to touch on the two most basic methods that I personally use and hopefully one sparks your interest.

**-1. Create an entityType in your metadataStore for user-type information.**

```
metadataStore.addEntityType({
    shortName: "User",
    dataProperties: {
        userId: { dataType: "String", isPartOfKey: true },
        userName: { dataType: "String" }
    }
});
```

This will add an entity type that you can serialize your return results to.  It is important to note here that if you change anything about that user without accepting changes locally it will try to save it next time you call `saveChanges()` so make sure you handle those situations if applicable.

Of course that isn't the only option.  You can most certainly just grab that user id from the query results without Breeze ever knowing about it or what it is for.

**-2. POJO**

```
function user(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.UserId = data.userId;
    self.UserName = data.userName;
}

// After your query returns data
query.execute().then(userReturned);

function userReturned(data) {
    // data is the returned object, which contains
    // an httpResponse which is what breeze returns
    // as the raw response
    new user(data.httpResponse.data);
}
```

This method basically just grabs the httpResponse when the promise returns and uses it to create a Plain Old JavaScript Object without Breeze knowing about it.  Of course for this to work you need to examine your data object that is returned and find what you are looking for and serialize that.

**Edit**

Your query locally should look like this -

```
query = breeze.entityQuery().from("Whatever").toType("CurrentUser").executeLocally(); 
em.executeQueryLocally(query);
```

Comment: var newQuery = _lookupsQuery.toType("CurrentUser").executeLocally(); gives error message 'An EntityQuery must have its EntityManager property set before calling 'executeLocally''

Comment: Have you tried adding `.using(em)` instead?  Error seems pretty straight forward...

Comment: Doesn't work with my lookups query, anyway, thanks for your efforts. I'll have to find another way of making it work.